# How do I get the metadata for a BigQuery query through the HTTP api

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm working on a type provider for F# and to implement it we need to get the schema for the query compile time, which means it has to be fast. As of the moment we run something like this:

```
bq query --format=json --dry_run=true --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT @a IS TRUE AS x, @b + 1 AS y, "foo" = @c AS z, ["tomas", "jansson"] as w, STRUCT("wat" as t, 69 as u) as v, [STRUCT(3, "allo" as g), STRUCT(5 as a, "yolo")] as u, STRUCT(["a"] as h) as t;'
```

which does exactly what we want, but it uses the `bq` tool. I want to know what the underlying http call is which I have trouble finding in the code base.

The reason I want to know the underlying code base is because I want to remove as much of third party dependencies as possible which might not be available on a build server or take a long time setting up.

Comment: A good tip to see the underlying http API calls being made by the `bq` tool is to use the api flags. For example: `bq query --apilog=true --format=json --dry_run=true --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT count(*) FROM lookerdata:cdc.project_tycho_reports;'` To see all the flags run `bq --help | grep "\--api"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can use

[`Jobs: insert`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) with [query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query) configuration property and [dryRun](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.dryRun) set to true

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Mikhail is right; only the `jobs.insert` API provides schema information. I'll use this answer just to document the current behavior.

Using the [`jobs.insert`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) API, here is a sample request and response:

```
PROJECT="YOUR_PROJECT_NAME"
QUERY="\"SELECT 1 AS x, 'foo' AS y, @b IS FALSE AS z;\""
REQUEST="{\"configuration\":{\"dryRun\":true,\"query\":{\"useLegacySql\":false,\"query\":${QUERY}}}}"
echo $REQUEST | \
curl -X POST -d @- -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
    https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/$PROJECT/jobs

(some parts omitted)
"statistics": {
 "query": {
  "schema": {
   "fields": [
    {
     "name": "x",
     "type": "INTEGER",
     "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
     "name": "y",
     "type": "STRING",
     "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
     "name": "z",
     "type": "BOOLEAN",
     "mode": "NULLABLE"
    }
   ]
  },
  "undeclaredQueryParameters": [
   {
    "name": "b",
    "parameterType": {
     "type": "BOOL"
    }
   }
  ],
  "statementType": "SELECT"
 }
```

Here is a sample request and response using [`jobs.query`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query), for the sake of comparison:

```
PROJECT="YOUR_PROJECT_NAME"
QUERY="\"SELECT 1 AS x, 'foo' AS y, @b IS FALSE AS z;\""
REQUEST="{\"kind\":\"bigquery#queryRequest\",\"dryRun\":true,\"useLegacySql\":false,\"query\":$QUERY}"
echo $REQUEST | \
  curl -X POST -d @- -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
    https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/$PROJECT/queries

{
 "kind": "bigquery#queryResponse",
 "jobReference": {
  "projectId": "<omitted>"
 },
 "totalBytesProcessed": "0",
 "jobComplete": true,
 "cacheHit": false
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that again first thing tomorrow. I tried dry run earlier but only got a number back and not the schema. Might have done something wrong.

Comment: it looks like I don't get the schema when using try run. The data I get back is: `{
 "kind": "bigquery#queryResponse",
 "jobReference": {
  "projectId": "uc-prox-development"
 },
 "totalBytesProcessed": "0",
 "jobComplete": true,
 "cacheHit": false
}` Tried the API on this page: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query#parameters

Comment: The other answer will work though, but the API should be updated to include schema when going straight to the query API and not jobs.

Comment: I updated my answer to show the difference in responses between the `insert` and `query` APIs. You could consider filing a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) to have the `query` API return schema information as well. Thanks!

Comment: reported an issue in BigQuery so you can track it :)