# How can I use the API of BigQuery in javascript?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible in javascript to get or insert data of BigQuery by Using API?

It does not working. (refer to the site https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
    <script>
      function start() {
        gapi.client.init({
          'apiKey': 'mykey',
        }).then(function() {
          return gapi.client.request({
            'path' : 'https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projectId/queries/jobId',
            'method' : 'GET'
            'params' : {'projectId':'myid', 'jobId':'myid'}
          });
        }).then(function(response) {
          console.log(response.result);
        }, function(reason) {
          console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
        });
      };
      gapi.load('client', start);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="results"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just want to test how to get data from bigquery by html using javascirpt without any setting on local pc.

Comment: What if you do a POST request? See this for an example of accessing the API using `curl`, for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43241909/6253347.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Import the Google Cloud client library
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

async function queryStackOverflow() {
  // Queries a public Stack Overflow dataset.

  // Create a client
  const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery();

  // The SQL query to run
  const sqlQuery = `SELECT repo.name FROM githubarchive.year.2019 
  where repo.name LIKE '%googlemaps%' 
  or repo.name LIKE '%google-maps%' 
  or repo.name LIKE '%google-maps-api%' 
  or repo.name LIKE '%googlemapsapi%' 
  Group by
  repo.name`;

  const options = {
    query: sqlQuery,
  };

  // Run the query
  const [rows] = await bigqueryClient.query(options);
console.log(rows);
}
queryStackOverflow();
```